# Como hacer una conexión a SQL Server con Laravel Homestead

Tags: laravel, php7, sql-server-2017

Buen día a todos tengo un problema al hacer una conexión a SQL Server usando Laravel Homestead. Con MySQL me funciona todo bien.

En mi archivo .env modifique db_connection,host,port,database.

```
DB_CONNECTION=sqlsrv
DB_HOST=MSSQLSERVER2
DB_PORT=1433
DB_DATABASE=crudlaravelsql
DB_USERNAME=
DB_PASSWORD=
```

En username y password no se que colocar ya que para conectarme a MSSQLSERVER lo hago con Windows Authentication:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y bueno en el archivo database.php no modifique se encuentra así:

```
'sqlsrv' => [
            'driver' => 'sqlsrv',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '1433'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
        ],
```

Para poder lograr hacer la conexión tendría que instalar algún driver porque usando XAMPP se descargan dos ddl, tendría que hacerlo?

Comment: Lo que descargas son dos DLL, no ddl :P No indicas en ninguna parte qué error te sale pero sí, seguramente debes descargar esos drivers en DLL para windows, del sitio que te indican en la respuesta

Answer (score 0):

Debes instalar los drivers de conexion.

Descargar los drivers de la página de Microsoft.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20098

Debes ingresar al link y descargarte el driver, por lo general es un .zip el cual tienes que descomprimir y colocar los dll dentro de la carpeta C:\xampp\php\ext.

en este post puedes encontrar mas documentacion al respecto:
https://www.carlosgonzalezgurrea.es/conectando-laravel-con-sql-server-2012/

Comment: Gracias por responder amigo pero no estoy usando xampp, estoy con laravel homestead.

Answer (score 0):

Te aconsejo que cambies la autenticación de SQLServer, no lo hagas por autenticación sino por IP/usuario

En database.php debes hacer dos cosas, primero arreglar la configuración de la conexión:

```
 'sqlsrv' => [
        'driver' => 'sqlsrv',
        'url' => env('127.0.0.1'), // la ip del servidor de bd
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '1433'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'crudlaravelsql'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'sa'),    // el usuario sa - superadmin
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'xxxxxx'),// El password
        'charset' => 'utf8',
        'prefix' => '',
        'prefix_indexes' => true,
    ],
```

Luego debes cambiar la conexión por defecto en database.php:

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Default Database Connection Name
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may specify which of the database connections below you wish
| to use as your default connection for all database work. Of course
| you may use many connections at once using the Database library.
|
*/

'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'sqlsrv'), // cambiar conexion
```

Esta configuración se corresponde a lo que indicaste en el archivo .env

Por último asegurate de tener instalado los drivers y que cumplas los requisitos https://laravel.com/docs/master/installation